# code for connecting 3 ultrasonic sensor, 1 buzzer, 1 LED in a Arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I need a code that connects 3 ultrasonic sensors, 1 buzzer, and 1 LED in a Arduino uno

I tried using this code the original code was only supposed to work with 1 sensor I tried modifying it but nothing seems to work and it keeps buzzing and flickering light randomly. It would be much appreciated if you could help.

```
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPinA = 7;
const int echoPinA = 2;
const int trigPinB = 3;
const int echoPinB = 4;
const int trigPinC = 5;
const int echoPinC = 6;
const int buzzer = 10;
const int ledPin = 12;

// defines variables
long durationA;
long durationB;
long durationC;
int distanceA;
int distanceB;
int distanceC;
int safetyDistanceA;
int safetyDistanceB;
int safetyDistanceC;


void setup() {
pinMode(trigPinA, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(trigPinB, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(trigPinC, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(echoPinA, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
pinMode(echoPinB, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
pinMode(echoPinC, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}


void loop() {
// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPinA, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPinA, LOW);

  digitalWrite(trigPinB, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPinB, LOW);

  digitalWrite(trigPinC, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPinC, LOW);

// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  durationA = pulseIn(echoPinA, HIGH);
  durationB = pulseIn(echoPinB, HIGH);
  durationC = pulseIn(echoPinC, HIGH);

// Calculating the distance
  distanceA= durationA*0.034/2; 
  distanceB= durationB*0.034/2; 
  distanceC= durationC*0.034/2; 

// DISTANCE 
  safetyDistanceA = distanceA;
  if (safetyDistanceA <= 5){
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else{
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

 safetyDistanceB = distanceB;
  if (safetyDistanceB <= 5){
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else{
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  
  safetyDistanceC = distanceC;
  if (safetyDistanceC <= 5){
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else{
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
// Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distanceA);
  Serial.println(distanceB);
  Serial.println(distanceC);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPinA = 7;
const int echoPinA = 2;
const int trigPinB = 3;
const int echoPinB = 4;
const int trigPinC = 5;
const int echoPinC = 6;
const int buzzer = 10;
const int ledPin = 12;

// defines variables
long durationA;
long durationB;
long durationC;
int distanceA;
int distanceB;
int distanceC;
int safetyDistanceA;
int safetyDistanceB;
int safetyDistanceC;


void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPinA, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(trigPinB, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(trigPinC, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPinA, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  pinMode(echoPinB, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  pinMode(echoPinC, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}


void loop() {
  // Sensor A
  digitalWrite(trigPinA, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPinA, LOW);
  durationA = pulseIn(echoPinA, HIGH);
  distanceA= durationA*0.034/2; 
  safetyDistanceA = distanceA;
  if (safetyDistanceA <= 5){
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

  // Sensor B
  digitalWrite(trigPinB, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPinB, LOW);
  durationB = pulseIn(echoPinB, HIGH);
  distanceB= durationB*0.034/2; 
  safetyDistanceB = distanceB;
  if (safetyDistanceB <= 5){
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  
  // Sensor C
  digitalWrite(trigPinC, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPinC, LOW);
  durationC = pulseIn(echoPinC, HIGH);
  distanceC= durationC*0.034/2; 
  safetyDistanceC = distanceC;
  if (safetyDistanceC <= 5){
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }

  // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance A: ");
  Serial.println(distanceA);
  Serial.print("Distance B: ");
  Serial.println(distanceB);
  Serial.print("Distance C: ");
  Serial.println(distanceC);
}
```